# get full image link using preg replace

Tags: php

i want to get full image from blogspot, url image like here

```
https://googleusercontent.com/-gGjtljhgg1294/WWErTJOTtsHI/AAAAAAABNiU/W_-jNZBxzQMS8gvgghkhkhljkljkhgjkgjh/w126-h126-p/DY-jNhgghjhhjghgjhg.jpg
```

how to  replace w126-h126-p to s0 for full size like :

```
https://googleusercontent.com/-gGjtljhgg1294/WWErTJOTtsHI/AAAAAAABNiU/W_-jNZBxzQMS8gvgghkhkhljkljkhgjkgjh/s0/DY-jNhgghjhhjghgjhg.jpg
```

my code

```
  $imgsf = preg_replace( '/w[0-9]-h[0-9][-]-p/' , 's0' , $imgurl);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of issues with your regex, your groups `[0-9]` don't allow for multiple digits (they need a `+` after them) and also you are trying to match two `-` in a row with `[-]-`. Also, it's easier to just write `\d` for `[0-9]`. Try this instead:

```
preg_replace('/w\d+-h\d+-p/', 's0', $imgurl);
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/jkml3)